# Pause the exiting of JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, runtime

I have code (runtime between 1 and 2 seconds) which I want to run everytime the computer shuts itself down (logging off a user out of a another system on another server).

I have already tried to add it to the `ShutdownHook` but the execution of the overgiven Thread is to slow - the thread gets killed before all commands could be executed.

Also tried to add it to a finally statement, that didn't help anything too.

What is IYO common practise for that case?

THX a lot.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277630/windows-shutdown-hook-on-java-application-run-from-a-bat-script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816858/detecting-that-jvm-is-shutting-down

Answer (score 1):

You will not get this to work robustly. `ShutdownHook` will only be called if the JVM is closed down gracefully. Ungraceful closes include the OS killing the process, or even a power failure.

An alternative in this instance is to maintain a "heartbeat" signal between your computer and the server which, if severed, logs the user off the server.

Comment: Hm.. Really unsatisfying.. Isn't there a way to pause the process like Word or eclipse when shutting the computer down?

Comment: Not reliably. Any such scheme can always be circumvented.

Comment: Allright, thx a lot. I'll try to make the process as fast as possible.